# Can you explain the meaning of base units behind the unit gray?

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis

The gray is a unit that measures energy absorbed per unit of mass. It's defined as one Joule per one kilogram. Which can be simplified to $m^2/s^2$.

Can you explain the meaning (interpretation) of absorbed dose expressed as square meters per second per second?

I believe this might seem like a silly, very soft question, but in most cases the units do make sense. For example, the fuel consumption is measured in length squared and XKCD manages to [provide an explanation](https://what-if.xkcd.com/11/) of what that area means.

Comment: "Which can be simplified to $m^2/s^2$": you may have reduced the dimensions to base SI units, but you have definetly not simplified in terms of physical interpretation. The original units of $J/kg$ are clearly more intuitive as the amount of energy absorbed per unit mass.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the radiation energy was absorbed as heat by a quantity of ideal gas having mass M  (where M is N·m, N is number of molecules, and m is mass of a molecule). Then Q = Δ(KE) = ½ N·m·Δ(v<sup>2</sup><sub>avg</sub>), so Q/M = ½ Δ(v<sup>2</sup><sub>avg</sub>). In that way J/kg corresponds to m<sup>2</sup>/s<sup>2</sup>.

Comment: Or similarly adding 1 joule of kinetic energy into a 1kg block in free space...

Answer (score 2):

It’s the square of the speed ($m/s$) you’d get if you could convert the radiation energy to kinetic. (Except for an inconvenient factor of two)